# Overlapping Label in IcCube Reporting

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I have a problem with overlapping labels in a bar charts.

[image]

The settings in the Axis label appear to be correct, because others settings do affect the rendering (bold, etc..) but spacing does not seem to be taken into account.

[image]

Any way to do a proper spacing of the labels, or actually to rotate them ?

**Update1:**

After applying the proposed settings this is what I get:
[image]

The labels are rotated but do not fit the widget.
I tried updating the margins, without a positive result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no options in the widget fields but you can rotate these labels using the "On Widget Options" hook.

You can find it on "Hooks" tab.

["On Widget Options" hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIx92.jpg) use this function:

```
function(context, options, $box) {
    for (var i = 0; i < options.categoryAxis.guides.length; i++) {
        options.categoryAxis.guides[i].labelRotation = 30; // rotation angle
    }
    return options;
}
```

Available fields for Guides can be checked [here](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide)

Custom code

[image]

Result
[image]

**UPDATE:**
You can change top margin using this code lines:

```
options.marginTop = 88; // Top margin
```

Just add it into "On Widget Options" hook:

```
function(context, options, $box) {
    options.marginTop = 88; // Top margin
    for (var i = 0; i < options.categoryAxis.guides.length; i++) {
        options.categoryAxis.guides[i].labelRotation = 30;
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: with this hook, you can practically copy any setting from amcharts directly.